# MySQL: SELECT millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset of about 32Million rows that I'm trying to export to provide some data for an analytics project.

Since my final data query will be large, I'm trying limit the number of rows I have to work with initially.  I'm doing this by running a create table on the main table (32Million) records with a   join on another table that's about 5k records.  I made indexes on the columns where the JOIN is taking place, but not on the other where conditions.  This query has been running for over 4 hours now.

What could I have done to speed this up and if there is something, would it be worth it to stop this query, do it, and start over?  The data set is static and I'm not worried about preserving anything or proper database design long-term.  I just need to get the data out and will discard the schema.

A simplified version of the query is below

```
CREATE TABLE RELEVANT_ALERTS
SELECT a.time, s.name,s.class, ...
FROM alerts a, sig s
WHERE a.IP <> 0  
AND a.IP not between x and y
AND s.class in ('c1','c2','c3')
```

Comment: why dont you just limit the number of records returned from the query? `LIMIT 5000`

Comment: I have to go over all the records to find what I need.   I'm using this query to trim down the main table into one that's more manageable for running other 'report' queries against.  Given the time involved, I don't want to have to run the query hundreds of times.

Comment: so make sure you have a pk and a fk in your tables and dont do a cross join like you are

Comment: is your problem solved? consider marking an answer as correct if so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try explain select to see what is going on first of all. Are your indexes properly setup?**

**Also you are not joining the two tables with their primary keys, is that on purpose?** Where is your primary key and foreign key?

**Can you also provide us with a table schema?**

Also, could your hardware be the problem? How much does RAM and processing power does it have? I hope you are not running this on single core processor as that is bound to take a long time

I have a table with 2,000,000,000 (2 billion rows, 219 Gig) and it doesn't take more than 0.3 seconds to execute similar query to yours with properly setup indexes. This is on a 8 (2ghz) core processor with 64gb ram. So not the beefiest setup for the size of the database, but the indexes are held in the memory, so the queries can be fast.

It should not take that long. Can you please make sure you have indexes on the a.IP And s.class.

Also cant you put a.IP <> = 0 comparison after a.IP not between x and y, so you already have a filtered set for 0 comparison (as that will compare every single record I believe)

You can move s.class as the first comparison depending on how many rows s table has to really speed up the comparison.

Comment: I just tried to create a FK between the two tables and I'm unable as the Alerts Table is partitioned.  I didn't do that intentionally, but it may have been that way from the original source database.

Comment: Can you please give me details of the schema even if it is partitioned.

Comment: Pointed in the right direction by this post, I changed the order of my where clause and created some new indexes.  This brought the query times down to about a minute.  Which given the hardware I'm on, is reasonable.

Comment: I am glad it is working now. If you do have any other troubles please contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is a full cross-join it seems. That will take really really long in any case. Is there no common field in both tables? Why do you need this join? If you really want to do this, you should first create two tables from `alerts` and `sig` that fulfill your `WHERE conditions` and then join the resulting tables if you must.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Vish.

In addition, depending on your query workload, you could probably change the internal storage engine to **MyISAM** if it is currently **InnoDB**, since Mysiam is more optimized for read-only queries.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Also, you could change the [isolation level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx) of your database. For example, to set isolation level to read uncommitted:

```
SET tx_isolation = 'READ-UNCOMMITTED';
```

Answer (score -3):

first try "[explain select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)" to see what is slowing it down then try to add some indexes if you don't have any

Comment: Should the OP blindly add indexes? How should they add indexes? To what columns? Could you include the syntax for 'explain select'?

Comment: Actually I did run an EXPLAIN before I started.  It led me to create one index, but a subsequent explain revealed no difference.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Here's the documentation on [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), basically it's a way to see how the query engine is going to process your statement without having to run it.

Comment: @user3195248 I *know* what explain is and what it does; the impetus for my comment was to let the OP know *in a gentle way* why his answer was getting downvoted / flagged.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker--Terribly sorry, I tagged the wrong user on that reply.

Answer (score -5):

Trust me, 4 hours is very normal: because you have a table of 32 millions rows and with the join you juste multiply 32 millions with 5000 so your query have a complexity of 320000000 * 5000 ...
to avoid that i suggest you to use an ETL WORFLOW ... Like Microsoft SSIS...
Withh SSIS you can reduce a lot the query's TIME...

Comment: 4 hours isn't normal and shouldn't be normal. this can be fixed... like make sub tables with the correct indexes so you can join them (without it being a cross join)... it can take seconds when set up properly